# Постоянная проверка соединения с Firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird

Как можно постоянно проверять соединение с базой Firebird. К примеру у меня есть Статус Панель, на которой показывается есть соединение с базой или нет. А то он показывает что нет соединения только если выполнить запрос. Как это осуществить, постоянную проверку соединения с базой?

Answer (score 1):

Если бы это пришлось сделать мне, я создал бы отдельный поток, где каждые N секунд запрашивал бы, скажем, системную дату из (забыл, как эта таблица в Firebird называется - аналог dual из Oracle). Но никогда этого не делал :-(

Comment: То есть? Зачем делать поток? По идее лучше наверно сделать отдельную процедуру которая будет проверять или спрашивать статус соединения, лишний запрос делать не надо и так база нагруженная. Но как это сделать?